# Why use cross Apply to get the values in XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, performance, cross-apply

Few days ago, i tried the Extended Events for replace the SQL Server profiler. 
Then i wanted to put the xel files generated in the sql server database with sql.

What i think odds, it's a lot of site use the function nodes with a Cross Apply to get the value in the XML, even if it's more slower than not to use it. 
I don't know if i am missing something?

Sample of my queries
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: You can cut bread with a chain saw or you might use some bare wire, but don't blame the tool, if the result is not convincing (even if it's very fast :-D )...

You **need** `.nodes()` if there are `1:n` related sub-nodes in order to retrieve them as a derived table.

Many people use `.nodes()` just to get a bit more readability into the code, especially with very deeply nested elements, when the `XPath` grows to some size...

You get a named *current node* from where you can continue with `XPath navigation` or `XQuery`. With multiple nested XML you can dive deeper and deeper using a cascade of `.nodes()`.

If you can be **sure** that there will be **only one element** below `<event>` with the name `<data>` with an attribute `@Name` with the value `NTCanonicalUserName` there's no need for `.nodes()`. Assumeably the fastest would be to use something like

```
/event[1]/data[@name="NTCanonicalUserName"][1]/value[1]/text()[1]
```

**Important!**
If there might be more than one `<event>` or more than one `<data>` with the given attribute, your "fast" call would return the first occurance whereever it is found. This might be the wrong one... And **you would never find out**, that there is another one...

Your "fast" call is fast, because the **engine knows in advance**, that there will be exactly one result. With `.nodes()` the eninge will have to look for further occurances and will do the overhead to create the structures for a derived table.

**General advise**
If you know something, the engine cannot know, but would make the reading faster, you should help the engine...

**Good to know**
Internally the *real / native XML data type* is not stored as the string representation you see, but as a hierarchically structured tree. Dealing with XML is astonishingly fast... In your case the search is just jumping down the tree directly to the wanted element.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. :)

Comment: If my XML field is a single root element with attributes as the 'data', I think you are saying I don't really need (or benefit from using) `CROSS APPLY .nodes()` right?

Comment: @Terry with small XMLs there won't be much difference. Using APPLY with nodes() might make things more readable. But in terms of "fast" it won't help.